# Bitwise circular shifting in an array

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a `uint8_t` typecast array of overall 36 bytes of data. I want to circularly shift the **bits** through the entire array (right shift). 
How can I do this? eg.:

```
uint8_t arr[3] = {0x03, 0x44, 0x32}
```

after one shift it should be:

```
arr[3] = {0x01, 0xa2, 0x19}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do a non-circular shift?  And why would the result of a circular shift take up an extra byte?

Comment: Circular shift right, otherwise known as a rotate right, implies that lowest bit in the sequence is circulated to the most significant bit. Using a single byte example 0x03 rotated right becomes 0x81. Where as the same value shifted right is 0x01. Which do you have in mind here?

Comment: @PeterCamilleri - I think the OP is asking to rotate the bits in the whole array. So the lowest bit of element `n` becomes the highest bit of element `n+1`. The lowest bit of the last element becomes the highest bit of the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may circular shift an array with the following code. It's commented so almost self-explanatory.

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[3] = {0x03, 0x44, 0x32};


    int i,
        l;


    uint8_t savedCarry,
            carry;


    // let `l` be the size (nr. of elements) of the array

    l = 3;


    // this will cause the array bit shift to be circular
    // by taking the "carry" bit (lowest bit) from the last element of the array
    // this "carry" bit will be used on the first element in the `for` loop

    carry = arr[ l - 1 ] & 1;


    // loop trought the array applying bit shift

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        savedCarry = arr[i] & 1;        // save the lowest bit  
        arr[i] = arr[i] >> 1;           // right shift
        if( carry )
        {
            arr[i] |= (uint8_t) 0x80;   // the lowest bit of the previuos element becomes the highest bit of the current one
        }
        carry = savedCarry;             // the lowest bit of this element will become the highest of the next one
    }


    // display hex output

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf( "0x%02x\n", arr[i] );
    }

    return( 0 );
}
```

Will output

```
0x01
0xa2
0x19
```

Note that as you right-shift a value you lose the lowest bit. That's why before the operation the lowest bit will be saved into `savedCarry`.

Before the end of each `for` iteration `savedCarry` will be copied into `carry` that will set the highest bit on the next array value (on the next iteration).

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each byte of the array.  For each byte, first check the low bit and if it is set then set a carry-out flag.  Then you can shift the byte right by one.

Repeat the above for the next byte, but first set a carry-in flag to the current value of the carry-out flag.  After shifting, check the carry-in flag and if it's set then set the high bit of the current byte.  Keep going until you hit the end of the array.  If the carry-out flag is set at the end, set the high bit of the first byte.

Comment: Might need to explain how to fiddle with the carry bit using C.  In fact, can you assume there *is* a carry bit?

Comment: @ScottHunter That should have been "carry flag".  Edited.

Comment: Initialise the carry flag as the low bit of the last element and you don't need to go back at the end...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array indices go from `0` to `N - 1`, one way to do this would be:

- Save the last bit of the last element. This will be used to circularly add as a carry to the first element:

  ```
  uint8_t circular_carry = (arr[N - 1] & 1) << 7;
  ```
- For each element `i` from `N - 1` to `1`, right shift the element (`arr[i] >> 1`), and set the lowest bit of the previous element to its highest (i.e. 8th) bit (`(arr[i - 1] & 1) << 7`):

  ```
  int i;
  for(i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      arr[i] >>= 1;                     // Right shift the (i)th byte
      arr[i] |= (arr[i - 1] & 1) << 7;  // Carry from the previous digit 
  }
  ```
- Right shift and add the `circular_carry` to the first element:

  ```
  arr[0] >>= 1;
  arr[0] += circular_carry;
  ```